# How to move between folders in ~/.bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias

I am creating some aliases to save keystrokes.
I am writing inside `~/.bashrc` the following:

```
alias work='cd /work/e674/e674/ouatu/' 
alias pythonvenv='cd /work/e674/e674/ouatu/PythonVirtualEnv_Smilei_happi/venv && source bin/activate && cd /work/e674/e674/ouatu/'
```

The first alias works and when I write in terminal `$ work` it goes to the specified directory. After writing `$ work` , the `$ pwd` command returns `/work/e674/e674/ouatu`

The second alias works up until it reaches the second `cd` command. THere, it doesn't go to the specified folder and calls the following error/warning and does NOT go into the specified folder:

```
-bash: /work/e674/e674/ouatu/: Is a directory
```

What is wrong with the last instruction of the second alias?
Thank you!

EDIT from comments: content of /bin/activate:

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly


if [ "${BASH_SOURCE-}" = "$0" ]; then
    echo "You must source this script: \$ source $0" >&2
    exit 33
fi

deactivate () {
    unset -f pydoc >/dev/null 2>&1 || true

    # reset old environment variables
    # ! [ -z ${VAR+_} ] returns true if VAR is declared at all
    if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:+_}" ] ; then
        PATH="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi
    if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME+_}" ] ; then
        PYTHONHOME="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME"
        export PYTHONHOME
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
    fi

    # This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
    # be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
    # past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
    if [ -n "${BASH-}" ] || [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION-}" ] ; then
        hash -r 2>/dev/null
    fi

    if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1+_}" ] ; then
        PS1="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1"
        export PS1
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi

    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    if [ ! "${1-}" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
    # Self destruct!
        unset -f deactivate
    fi
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

VIRTUAL_ENV='/lus/cls01095/work/e674/e674/ouatu/PythonVirtualEnv_Smilei_happi/venv'
if ([ "$OSTYPE" = "cygwin" ] || [ "$OSTYPE" = "msys" ]) && $(command -v cygpath &> /dev/null) ; then
    VIRTUAL_ENV=$(cygpath -u "$VIRTUAL_ENV")
fi
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
if ! [ -z "${PYTHONHOME+_}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="$PYTHONHOME"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="${PS1-}"
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        PS1="${PS1-}"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) ${PS1-}"
    fi
    export PS1
fi

# Make sure to unalias pydoc if it's already there
alias pydoc 2>/dev/null >/dev/null && unalias pydoc || true

pydoc () {
    python -m pydoc "$@"
}

# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "${BASH-}" ] || [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION-}" ] ; then
    hash -r 2>/dev/null
fi
```

Comment: it can be something in `bin/active` file, if `source bin/activate` fails `cd /work/e674/e674/ouatu` won't be executed

Comment: that works and the venv is activated after running this alias

Comment: @velenos14 Are you sure? It might successfully activate the venv and *then* get an error. Try running `cd /work/e674/e674/ouatu/PythonVirtualEnv_Smilei_happi/venv && source bin/activate` (i.e. without the final `cd` command) and see if you get that error. If that's not the source of the problem, try running `set -x` (turn on execution tracing), then use the alias and see what command is generating the error (then use `set +x` to turn tracing back off).

Comment: Edit your question and add the content of the file bin/active.

Comment: @bac0n, I edited the question with the content of that file!

Comment: VIRTUAL_ENV= shows a different path/root?

Comment: Is it required to run the "activate" script from within `/work/e674/e674/ouatu/PythonVirtualEnv_Smilei_happi/venv` directory, ie. do you need to cd there and then go back? If not, then maybe change your `pythonvenv` alias to `cd /work/e674/e674/ouatu && source PythonVirtualEnv_Smilei_happi/venv/bin/activate` ?